# how to use header and footer in web page

Tags: css, jsp

this is footer file used in html 
    footeradmin.jsp    to see your page nice

```
        <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
            pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <link href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
         <script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/SpryCollapsiblePanel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/SpryMenuBar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/SpryCollapsiblePanel.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/SpryMenuBarVertical.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="tinybox.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>        
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
        <ul>
          <li style="border-left: medium none;"><a href="nsephome.jsp">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="aboutusadmin.jsp">About&nbsp;Us</a></li>
           <li><a href="Contactusadmin.jsp">Contact Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="feedbackadmin.jsp">Feedback</a></li>
          <li><a href="index.jsp">Logout</a></li>
           <li><a href="sitemapadmin.jsp">Site map</a></li>
        </ul>
        <p>Copyright &copy; 2013. Designed by <a>****</a></p>
        </div>
        </div>

        </body>
        </html>
```

this is header file I used in web page
headeradmin.jsp   use this file to look your web page good

```
        <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
            pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Header</title>
         <script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/SpryCollapsiblePanel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/SpryMenuBar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/SpryCollapsiblePanel.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/SpryMenuBarVertical.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/style2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/tinybox.js"></script>
        <link href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/tinystyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        </head>
        <body>
        <div class="main-out">
        <div class="main">
        <div class="page">
        <div class="top">
        <div class="header">
        <div class="header-top">
        <h1>National <span>Self Employment Program</span></h1>
        <p>Call Us: 987 3478 278</p>
        </div>
        <div class="topmenu">
        <ul>
         <li></li>
          <li><a href="nsephome.jsp">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="aboutusadmin.jsp">About&nbsp;Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="Contactusadmin.jsp">Contact Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="feedbackadmin.jsp">Feedback</a></li>
          <li><a href="index.jsp">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div style="height:550px; width:980px;margin-top:5px;">
        <div style="height:600px;width:160px;float:left;">
        <div style="width:160px;height:20px;background-color:#708090;float:left;"><FONT color="white"><center><b>Our Services</b></center></FONT></div>
        <%@include file="verticalbar1.jsp"%>
        </div>
        <div style="height:600px;width:20px;float:left;">
        </div>
        <div style="height:600px;width:800px;">

        </body>
        </html>
```

this page include in headerfile
verticalbar1.jsp to see your page nice

```
        <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
            pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
        <link href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/SpryCollapsiblePanel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/SpryMenuBar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/SpryCollapsiblePanel.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/SpryMenuBarVertical.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/bank.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="tinybox.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div id="CollapsiblePanel1" class="CollapsiblePanel" style="float:left;margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:10px;"> 
               <ul id="MenuBar1" class="MenuBarVertical">
                  <li><a  href="empregister.jsp">Create Employee</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a  href="empupdate.jsp">Read Employee</a>
                   </li>
                    <li><a  href="employee_list.jsp">Employee List</a>
                  <li><a  href="empdelete.jsp">Delete Employee</a>

                  </li>
                  <li><a href="feed1.jsp">Feedbacks</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a class="MenuBarItemSubmenu" href="#">Opinion poll</a>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="SubmitQuestion.jsp" >Post Question</a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="showpolling.jsp" >View Opinions</a>
                      </li>
                      </ul></li>

                </ul>

              </div> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
             <!--
        var CollapsiblePanel1 = new Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel("CollapsiblePanel1", {contentIsOpen:false});
        var MenuBar1 = new Spry.Widget.MenuBar("MenuBar1", {imgRight:"../../../SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarRightHover.gif"});
        //-->
        </script>
        <center>
        <img src="../images/emp2.JPG" alt="emp1" width="170" height="200"></img></center>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Too much code... What do you want to do ?

Comment: How about creating a Layout Page?

Answer (score 2):

The `jsp:include` element is processed when a JSP page is **executed**. The include action allows you to include either a *static or a dynamic resource* in a JSP file. The results of including static and dynamic resources are quite different. If the resource is static, its content is inserted into the calling JSP file. If the resource is dynamic, the request is sent to the included resource, the included page is executed, and then the result is included in the response from the calling JSP page.
The syntax for the `jsp:include` element is:

```
<jsp:include page="includedPage" />
```

You can include both `hearder.jsp` and `footer.jsp` into your `verticalbar1.jsp`

```
..........
.........
<jsp:include page="header.jsp" />
.........
........
.....
<jsp:include page="footer.jsp" />
```

#### Related link

- [Java EE Reusing Content in JSP Pages](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnajb.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use :

```
<jsp:include page="..." />
```

to include the page you want at the top of your "body content" page and at the bottom for the footer.